# How can I write this query efficiently in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three tables: Accounts, Investments, and Games. An Investment has an account_id, game_id, some statistic counters, and is created the first time an Account participates in a Game.

I want to provide a JSON list of the latest Games along with the user's Investment in that Game, like this:

```
[{id: 666, name: "Foobar", ..., investment: {tokens: 58, credits: 42, ...}},...]
```

If they have not yet participated in the game, I still want to include an Investment object with default values, so I overrode the `serializable_hash` function in my Game model:

```
# game.rb
has_many :investments
def serializable_hash(options=nil)
  options ||= {}
  i = investments.find_or_initialize_by_account_id options[:uid]
  {:id => id, ..., :investment => i.serializable_hash}
end
```

However, when I run something like `Game.find(list_of_ids).to_json(:uid => current_user.id)`, Rails does a separate query on the Investments table for each Game. I tried `Game.includes(:investments).find(list_of_ids).to_json(:uid => current_user.id)` but not only does that load the investments for all users, it still does a separate query for each game to find or initialize the investment object.

In short, given a list of game IDs and an account id, what's a clean way to load the associated Investment objects that exist in one query, and initialize the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to give the list of ids to the server in one go. I use the `IN` operator for this:

```
Game.includes(:investments).where("games.id IN (?)", list_of_ids)
```

Comment: That runs the same query I had above, Game.includes(:investments).find(list_of_ids)

Comment: @Violet In that case, it must be the `includes` call that's making them separate.